# sqlalchemy treatment of attributes on read (staleness)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

This might be a silly question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Let's say I pull some values:

```
widgets = session.query(Widget).all()
for widget in widgets:
    # ... do lots of things here
    # ... some other thread could be updating these widgets!
    if widget.is_ready: 
       do_something()
```

Does reading the property of widget actually check the database? Is there a way to make it do so explicitly without doing another query?

I'm worried the value read might be stale.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The values will not be updated. To update objects you need push every object into a session transaction and commit like:

```
widgets = session.query(Widget).all()
for widget in widgets:
  widget.name = widget.name  + '_widget_name'
  db.session.add(widget)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Not what I asked. I asked if reading a value would make a database call - not that updating it myself would require an update through the session.